# grep or map to find use statements in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl module which takes another file as input and prints all the use statements(except strict and warnings)

```
my @result = grep /use\s+([^;(strict|warnings)]+)/, @file;
```

This prints :

```
use Package1;
use Package2;
```

However I want only the "Package1" part. So when map is used:

```
my @result = map /use\s+([^;(strict|warnings)]+)/, @file;
```

this returns wrong values.(returns first 2 or 3 characters)

```
my @result = map /use\s+([^;]+)/, @file;
```

returns Package1,Package2,strict,warnings.

May I know how to correct the regex in the first map statement?

Thanks

Comment: Is this just a test case for learning regexes and map/grep, or are you actually trying to find use/require statements? If the latter there are modules for doing this.

Comment: @JoelBerger the latter. Could you point me in the right direction? thanks

Comment: It seems that Schwern beat me to it. That said see my comment there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw in a `grep` to filter:

```
my @result = grep { !/^(?:strict|warnings)$/ } map /use\s+([^;]+)/, @file;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are modules for doing this.  [Perl::PrereqScanner](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl%3a%3aPrereqScanner) is what [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aTutorial) uses and I've found it works pretty well.

And Neil Bowers has [a nice review of the available solutions](http://neilb.org/reviews/dependencies.html).  Thanks @JoelBerger for pointing that out in the comments.

For general purpose Perl code scanning it's best to use [PPI](https://metacpan.org/module/PPI) which has an understanding of Perl grammar.  Things like Perl::PrereqScanner and [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl%3a%3aCritic) use it.

Comment: Neil Bowers has a nice review article on the matter: http://neilb.org/reviews/dependencies.html